# Variable number of parameters in sass mixin and looping over each

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, neat

I'm using [Bourbon Neat](http://neat.bourbon.io/) in my project and Neat has this *neat* (ha!) little mixin for media queries:

```
$xs-media: new-breakpoint(min-width 1px max-width 480px);
@include media($xs-media) {
  // your styles
}
```

But `@include media` doesn't support multiple breakpoints. So I'm trying to do this:

```
@mixin multiple-media($breakpoints...) {
  @each $breakpoint in $breakpoints {
    @include media($breakpoint) {
      @content
    }
  }
}
```

I can then use multiple breakpoints on it:

```
$xs-media: new-breakpoint(min-width 1px max-width 480px);
// $sm-media: ...
// $md-media: ...
@inlclude multiple-media($xs-media, $sm-media, $md-media) {
  // my styles
}
```

But the compiled CSS doesn't quite work and look right. This is what gets generated (Just an example of what happens):

```
@media screen and (min-width: min-width) {
      .instagram-widget .instagram-widget__images-container > a > img {
        width: 25%; } }
    @media screen and (min-width: min-width) {
      .instagram-widget .instagram-widget__images-container > a > img {
        width: 25%; } }
    @media screen and (min-width: min-width) {
      .instagram-widget .instagram-widget__images-container > a > img {
        width: 25%; } }
```

`@media screen and (min-width: min-width) {` ??

Comment: What do you use to compile the SCSS? I just recreated this in codepen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZjWxN and if you click on 'View compiled' in the CSS block, it looks just fine, so I think it's your compiler problem.

Comment: @Foxhoundn thanks for having a look. I'm using node-sass/llibsass https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass . This is so frustrating

Comment: What sass version are you using? I just tried it and there was no problem with Sass 3.4.22 (Selective Steve).

Comment: @Foxhoundn I was using node-sass ^3.5.0 and I changed it to ^3.5.3 and it's working now! :D